# 2 DIVS inside parent DIV

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<div id ="game">
    <div id = "prodClick">
    Prod/Click:
    <div id="test">

    </div>
    </div>
        <div id = "image">
    <image src="assets/ressources.png" usemap="#upgrade" class = "mainImage"></image>   
    <map name="upgrade">
      <area shape="circle" style="display:block;" coords="98,46,22" href="/login/game/upgrade/boisClick.php">
      <area shape="circle" style="display:block;" coords="390,38,22" href="/login/game/upgrade/boisClick.php">
      <area shape="circle" style="display:block;" coords="98,436,22" href="/login/game/upgrade/boisClick.php">
      <area shape="circle" style="display:block;" coords="395,436,22" href="/login/game/upgrade/boisClick.php">
      <area shape="circle" style="display:block;" coords="208,185,22" href="/login/game/upgrade/boisClick.php">
      <area shape="circle" style="display:block;" coords="322,183,22" href="/login/game/upgrade/boisClick.php">
      <area shape="circle" style="display:block;" coords="208,305,22" href="/login/game/upgrade/boisClick.php">
      <area shape="circle" style="display:block;" coords="322,303,22" href="/login/game/upgrade/boisClick.php">
    </map>
    </div>
    <div id = "info">
    Prod/Heure
    </div>
</div>
<div id="end">

</div>
```

So `game` div has a width of `1000px` and an height of `500px`.
`ProdClick` div has a width of `250px` and an height of `500px`.
`image` div has a width of `500px` and an height of `500px`.
...

The problem is `prodClick` is correctly placed but it is filling the rest of the width with a kind of margin
And then I had the `image` div instead of going to the right of `prodClick` div it is going under because it is filled by the margin

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySpOT.png)

Any solutions Sorry for my English I'm french

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your **CSS**:

```
#prodClick, #image{
    display: inline-block; // get rid off unnecessary margin
}
```

By the way, your English is **parfait**! **:-)**